# How to reverse an ordering operation on data table in R?

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

Let DT be an examplary data table.
DT2 is constructed from DT by sorting each column independently.

As an example the table DT:

| ID | Letter |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | B |
| 4 | A |
| 3 | C |
| 2 | D |
| 5 | E |

becomes the table DT2:

| ID | Letter |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | D |
| 5 | E |

In reordering_dt I have saved what orderings I used to make the transformation from DT to DT2.

```r
# The original data table
DT <- data.table(
  ID = c(1, 4, 3, 2, 5),
  Letter = c("B", "A", "C", "D", "E")
)
# The "sorted" data table
DT2 <- DT[, lapply(.SD, function(col) col[order(col)])]

# storing what orderings we used to get DT2 from DT
reordering_dt <- as.data.table(lapply(DT, order))
```

Using only reordering_dt and DT2, how can I get DT again?

I should be able to make the transformation if I can do something like this:

```r
recovered_DT <- DT2[, lapply(.SD, function(col) col[order(X)])]
```

with X being the corresponding column in reordering_dt.

However I don't know how to specify X correctly.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding Doesn't reordering_dt contain the necessary side-information?

Comment: no, `reordering_dt` has overwritten the original information from `DT`, so you don't have any side information if you view from `reordering_dt` only.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding What do you mean by overwritten?
I thought that if reordering_dt[1,"Name"] = 5, that means that DT2[1,"Name"] was originally in DT[5,"Name"].

Comment: aha, sorry that I mixed up `reordering_dt` with `DT2` in your question. Yes, you can recover from `DT2` to `DT`, and `reordering_dt` gives the side information. Then the solution by @r2evans can answer your question.

Comment: another option is `DT2[,Map(\`[\`, .SD, reordering_dt)]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, we can reverse it using this:

```r
DT3 <- Map(function(val, ord) val[order(ord)], DT2, reordering_dt) |>
  as.data.table()
DT3
#       ID Letter
#    <num> <char>
# 1:     1      B
# 2:     4      A
# 3:     3      C
# 4:     2      D
# 5:     5      E
all.equal(DT, DT3)
# [1] TRUE
```

If you're working with significantly large datasets, I suggest doing `order(.)` only once, perhaps

```r
reordering_dt <- as.data.table(lapply(DT, order))
DT2b <- Map(function(val, ord) val[ord], DT, reordering_dt) |>
  as.data.table()
all.equal(DT2, DT2b)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: I just tested it on a larger toy example. When using order in your answer instead of rank it works. Rank yields 3 missmatches.

Comment: Yeah, I know there's a logical difference and couldn't reproduce it with this toy dataset, thanks for confirming and getting back to me. I edited it to include `order(ord)` instead, hope it works well enough for you.

Comment: thank you. Why does that work? I've not really worked with Map before...

Comment: `Map` is analogous to `lapply`, except that while `lapply` works on one vector/list at a time, `Map` "zips" 1 or more together. `lapply(X, FUN)` is the same as `Map(FUN, X)`, for comparison; however, `Map` gets more interesting with multiple vectors/lists, try `Map(function(a, b) a * b, 1:10, 2:11)` for an anti-efficient demonstration of `(1:10) * (2:11)`

Comment: Thanks again. I banged my head against the brick wall for clearly too many hours.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use `order(order(x))` to recover the initial, for example

```
> set.seed(0)

> (x <- runif(5))
[1] 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078

> (xsorted <- x[order(x)])
[1] 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.8966972 0.9082078

> (xhat <- xsorted[order(order(x))])
[1] 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078

> all.equal(x, xhat)
[1] TRUE
```

but you should know that `xsorted[order(order(x))]` needs the `order` information of `x`, which is the "side information" as I said in the comment.

In other words, *you can never recover `xhat` from `xsorted` **only** (since you need `x` as well).*

Comment: I'm trying to see why `order(order(.))` and `rank(order(.))` work the same here, yet there is something fundamentally different about the logic behind them ...

Comment: @r2evans `rank` will have a different treatment on ties, but I guess both work the same for OP's purpose.

Comment: good point, though in this case since it is defined originally with `order`, there should be no ties, right?

Comment: @r2evans yes, exactly.